# Guidance for the math used in phys

Tags: education, mathematics

My goal is to be become a physicist but I am concerned about my math skills (i am pretty decent in maths) ,i know the computational part but I'm not good in geometric or intuitive part of it,so i decided that i must be thorough in both the numbers and the concepts that govern them ,but I don't know where to start,like from which chapter do i need to understand in an intuitive way,can someone suggest a hierarchy/order for learning maths in intuitive way from basics to advanced?,it would be helpful....

Comment: Hi and welcome to physics.SE! I'm afraid such open-ended "advice" questions don't fit well into our Q&A model, which works best with questions that can in principle have an objectively correct answer. If you are looking for recommendations to study specific branches of physics (and the math required) you may want to browse the [tag:resource-recommendations] tag.

Comment: What do you mean by "*learning maths in intuitive way*"? Usually, the intuitive part is the physics, the reality, the real-world applications, while the math tends to be the non-intuitive description of reality. I would simply suggest you to find a good introductory physics text book, such as [University Physics](http://www.mypearsonstore.com/bookstore/university-physics-with-modern-physics-plus-mastering-9780321982582), in which they go through all math along the way. If you along the way need to know how they do an integral or so, then look that specific issue up, when you come about it.